# Node access based on the user reference field

Tags: 9

I have a content type that is used for temporary access. The node is created and has an expiration date; it's deleted after that date. On this node there is a user reference field; only the users added to this field should have access to viewing this node. I can't find a hook to handle this access. In Drupal 7 I used `hook_node_access()`, but it doesn't seem to exist for Drupal 9.

The only information I'm looking for is how to tap into the access privileges for a given node type. After that I can handle the logic of what users are contained in the reference field.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 9 still uses `hook_node_access()`. It's documented under [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access/9.3.x) because it's invoked for every existing entity, not just for the Node entity.
If *mymodule* is the module that implements that hook for the Node entity, the function implementing the hook would be `mymodule_node_access()`, exactly as in Drupal 7. The Drupal 7 code still needs to be ported to Drupal 9, as many details changed between Drupal 7 and Drupal 9.

If then you need to check the access for different entities, you could implement [`hook_entity_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_access/9.3.x).